# Full Implications of SMB mount option "noserverino"?

Tags: linux, samba

Working with Ubuntu-based systems.

Having run into a samba mount giving a stale file handle, the advice around the net seems to be adding `noserverino` as an option for the mount.

Reading the documentation, it states:

> You can also use "noserverino" mount option to generate inode numbers smaller than 2 power 32 on the client. But you may not be able to detect hardlinks properly.

This doesn't really say much, for me. I don't see what issues could arise from this.

What negative consequences could there be for not knowing certain files are the same hardlink, unless you have a system going where you manually change files a bunch of times?

As for the "generate inode numbers smaller than 2 power 32 on the client" part... am I to assume that any numbers above this will still be generated on the server and properly communicated to the client?

Considering this is a non-default option and it's summary is so small, I'm a bit worried about unknown implications and/or behavior if you use this.

Can anyone elaborate on this? Or give some certainty that this won't break after a year? Or with a filesystem with too many files?